Firebase IOS purchase events all conversion value display zero in Google Ads
I have firebase analytics installed in my iOS app and I am triggering a purchase event on the purchase page. Likewise, there is exactly the same code on the Android side. I have already developed my mobile application using webview and cordova.
Then, by connecting Google Ads and Firebase, I track who clicked on the ad and purchased from my mobile application and how much sales I made. This works without any problems for Android. When I look at the firebase panel for iOS, I see the conversion value. When I look at the Google Ads panel, while the conversion count is reflected for IOS, the conversion value is always zero.
Firebase panel IOS revenue:

Google Ads IOS revenue:

My JS code for sending purchase event:
firebase.analytics.logEvent('purchase', {
    'transaction_id': transaction.request_id,
    'affiliation': transaction.affiliation,
    'value': transaction.revenue,
    'currency': 'TRY',
    'items': analytics_items
});

What do you think could cause this error?
Edit:
When i look from google analytics firebase section. I see all purchase event coming from Direct traffic.
Img:

But when i look fpr the android purchase event they coming from different sources.
Img:

As far as I understand, iOS cannot reconcile incoming purchase events with Google Ads. What could be the reason for this? However, on the Google Ads side, there is a conversion count for IOS, but the conversion value is zero.
